# como hacer consultas de 3 tablas diferentes en mysql en capos diferentes

Tags: sql

Disculpen, estoy haciendo una consulta donde necesito datos de 3 tablas diferentes y la consulta se ejecuta pero en la columna de la tabla 1 y la tabla dos los datos se repiten y los de la 3ra columna si se muestran como deben, que tengo que arreglar en mi consulta para que me muestre todo bien?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Giancarlo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Comment: Añade el código como código y no como imagen para facilitar la lectura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como estas?
Te comento, lo que veo es que estas haciendo un FullJoin

Por lo que veo quieres hacer un INNER JOIN (Relacionando las tablas)

Si este es el caso primero busca una columna que puedas relacionar en las tablas y luego has las consultas.

```
SELECT t1.campo1, t2.campo2, t3.campo3
FROM tabla1 t1
inner JOIN tabla2 t2 ON t1.columnaCompartidax = t2.columnaCompartidat2 
inner JOIN tabla3 t1 ON t1.columnaCompartidax = t3.columnaCompartidat3
```

Ademas si necesitas profundizar sobre estos temas te recomiendo

### https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

En caso que puedas devolver una tabla desordenada:

```
SELECT 'Titulo' as 'Key', titulos.titulo 'Value'
FROM titulos
where clausula
------------
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Autores' as 'Key', autores.nombre as 'Value'
FROM autores
where clausula
------------
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Genero' as 'Key', generos.nombre as 'Value'
FROM titulos
where clausula

El resultado seria 

    Key || value
_____________________________
  Titulo|| Ejemplo de titulo
  Titulo|| Otro Titulo
 Autores|| Autor1
 Genero || Policial
```

---

Saludos.

Comment: Hola, que tal. gracias

Es que el problema que veo es que no son tablas que deban estar relacionadas pues no tienen registros en comun lo unico es que necesito encontrar con la sentencia LIKE la palabra que se requiere pero no se como hacerle

Comment: @Luciano los JOINS solo funcionan con tablas relacionadas no?

Comment: Es arbitraria que la consulta salga con ese formato de salida?
Es decir si no tienen relacion, podrias devolver todo de forma desordenada
Podrias devolver:
Descripcion;        Valor
ejTitulo         ; un titulo de ejemplo:
ejBody:

Comment: @AlfredoPaz relacionadas de forma conceptual, no necesariamente a nivel de keys

Comment: Entonces que es lo que podria hacer para que los datos de las primeras dos columnas no se repitan? Ya que si sabia que para los joins necesitaban estar relacionadas de alguna manera